# Freelancing on highly skilled migrant visa in NL

Tags: visa, working-visas, netherlands

My husband started working in nl on a highly skilled migrant visa in 2016 and in 2019, he switched to freelancing. At the time he consulted a few lawyers and because his residence card at the back says 'kennismigrant en zelfstandig toegestaan', he has been since then working as a freelancer. I came here just two months ago on spouse visa without hiccups as well, but now IND is saying that his visa is invalid after 2019. They have asked for more documents obviously and the letter from IND is strongly worded so we are confused. My husband has submitted all his agreements and contracts of the past 1.5 years of freelancing. Can anyone offer some insight here?

Answer (score 4):

We got the answer for this. The law is quite confusing but IND was quite clear: you cannot pursue freelancing fulltime if you are on highly skilled migrant and self-employed visa, so now we either need to find a recognized sponsor or go on a complete self-employed visa. A lot of people commit the same mistake but please learn from our mistake, and make sure you are always under an employer who is recognized as a highly skilled migrant visa sponsor and never pursure freelancing fulltime while on HSM visa.